# Sharepoint change post layout has only 3 style Basic,Boxed,Inline?

Tags: blog

Can I find more **style**. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those 3 have been the standard since version 2013, if you want different ones you need to create them with css

Comment: have you some tutorial about how to create that. Thanks

Comment: i have not seen any online